# Repositioning Children in RelativePanel through VisualStates

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, win-universal-app

I have Relative Panel with a bunch of Children in it. I want to change the position of children by AdoptiveTrigger in VisualStates.
The problem is when i want to change an element position from Below of other element to right of that element, I've to remove the value of Below Attached Property and then set the RightOf property to make it work,otherwise it crashes the app.
Now i want to now how to remove that Below Value?
I've tried to 
a.reset the binding in Properties Window for each state and then assigning my values
b.setting that value to empty string like "";
c.Ignoring that property.
None of these worked!
please help me!

Answer (score 2):

Setting the attached property `RelativePanel.Below` to empty can work. Besides this we can also slove this problem by setting `AlignTopWith` or `AlignVerticalCenterWith` property.

This works because the priority of `AlignTopWith` is higher than `Below` and for `AlignVerticalCenterWith` property, it is applied if there is no conflict. As my test, `AlignVerticalCenterWith`'s priority is also higher than `Below`.

For more information, please see the [**Conflicting relationships**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.relativepanel.aspx#conflicting_relationships) section in `RelativePanel` class.

Following is the sample I used to test:

```
<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
        <VisualStateGroup>
            <VisualState>
                <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                    <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowWidth="600" />
                </VisualState.StateTriggers>
                <VisualState.Setters>
                    <Setter Target="BlueRect.(RelativePanel.Below)" Value="" />
                    <Setter Target="GreenRect.(RelativePanel.RightOf)" Value="BlueRect" />
                    <Setter Target="GreenRect.(RelativePanel.Below)" Value="RedRect" />
                    <!--<Setter Target="GreenRect.(RelativePanel.AlignVerticalCenterWith)" Value="BlueRect" />-->
                    <!--<Setter Target="GreenRect.(RelativePanel.AlignTopWith)" Value="BlueRect" />-->
                </VisualState.Setters>
            </VisualState>
        </VisualStateGroup>
    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>

    <RelativePanel>
        <Rectangle x:Name="RedRect"
                   Width="100"
                   Height="100"
                   Fill="Red" />
        <Rectangle x:Name="BlueRect"
                   Width="100"
                   Height="200"
                   Fill="Blue"
                   RelativePanel.Below="RedRect"
                   RelativePanel.RightOf="RedRect" />
        <Rectangle x:Name="GreenRect"
                   Width="100"
                   Height="100"
                   Fill="Green"
                   RelativePanel.Below="BlueRect"
                   RelativePanel.RightOf="RedRect" />
    </RelativePanel>
</Grid>
```

It works like:
[image]

Comment: Tnx , It seems that it works ,I'll check it , but for now I've submitted my app to store a few hours ago :(

Answer (score 0):

You can do

```
<Setter Target="SomeElement.(RelativePanel.Below)" Value="{x:Null}" />
```

Comment: This gives me this Message : Catastrophic failure (Exeption fromHRESULT 0x8000FFFF (E_UNEXPECTED))